# Automatic div Overflow into parent div

Tags: html, css

I have a `<div>` (container, fixed sizes) where I would like to add smaller `<div>`s (NOT fixed sizes) in this way:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/D9Irf.png

I am trying to make it to automatically "overflow" the `<div>`s and putting them next to the top `<div>`, when reaching the end of the Container `<div>`.

I'm able to achieve this by using additional `<div>`s that hold each column in the Container `<div>`, but I have to calculate the sizes each time and remove `<div>`s from columns.

Is there a way to do this? Thank you :)

**EDIT: Sebil's solution worked, but as you can see there is a margin between the 2 columns. How do i get rid of it?**

Here's a snippet:

```css
.container {
  width: 600px;
  height: 500px;
  background-color: blue;
  columns: 2;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.celldiv {
  width: 200px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: yellow;
  box-shadow: inset 2px 2px 2px #000;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="celldiv">TEST 1</div>
  <div class="celldiv">TEST 2</div>
  <div class="celldiv">TEST 3</div>
  <div class="celldiv">TEST 4</div>
  <div class="celldiv">TEST 5</div>
  <div class="celldiv">TEST 6</div>
  <div class="celldiv">TEST 7</div>
  <div class="celldiv">TEST 8</div>
  <div class="celldiv">TEST 9</div>
  <div class="celldiv">TEST 10</div>
  <div class="celldiv">TEST 11</div>
</div>
```

Comment: We need a [mcve], not an image. And for me, your image doesn't even load.

Comment: I think flexbox is probably what you want: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's a perfect case for the correct use of `display: flex;`

If you set the `flex-direction: column;` you 'rotate' the natural reading direction to 'top to bottom' and with `flex-wrap: wrap;` you make sure that the content could not overflow outside of the container.

Make sure that the divs inside the container have enough space to fit in two columns (or more) by giving them a proper width.

**NOTE:** If you give the divs more properties like `border` or `margin` it could be that you have to calculate the `width` to make them fit again.

Here's my basic example with different div heights (like you mentioned):

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-wrap: wrap;

  width: 500px;
  height: 800px;
  border: 3px solid darkkhaki;
}

div {
  width: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div><p>1 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua.</p></div>
  <div><p>2 Lorem ipsum dolor sit</p></div>
  <div><p>3 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor</p></div>
  <div><p>4 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua.</p></div>
  <div><p>5 Lorem</p></div>
  <div><p>6 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua.</p></div>
  <div><p>7 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy</p></div>
  <div><p>8 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua.</p></div>
</div>
```

Comment: With this approach however, OP would need to set a fixed height to the container; I'm aware the question says *"(container, fixed sizes)"*, just wanted to point out that this won't work unless the container has the explicit height set

Comment: I've been already using display:flex! :D but i did not use the flex-direction property.

Both your answer and @Jacob answer works, your one fits better what i wanted to do. But i still have a problem:
https://jsfiddle.net/oc70fzpq/1/
This is a jsfiddle. As you can see there is a margin between the 2 columns. How do i get rid of it?

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [`columns` CSS property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/columns):

```
.container {
  columns: 2;
}
```

Comment: This works but i got a strange behavior, maybe because of the display:flex property

Comment: Yeah, `columns` is a way of doing it without geting flexbox involved. I'd definitely go with @sebil if you're using flexy stuff.